# OSX 10.6.8 can't find OD users after DNS change

Tags: mac-osx, internal-dns, opendirectory

I recently switched out a DNS server, to a more stable one, but now of my mac servers are giving me some trouble. When the network cable is in, I'm getting stuck at the login screen, even when trying local users, so I pulled it out.

After that I successfully logged in to a local admin, and checked whether the mac server uses the new DNS server correctly:

```
gentofte:~ admin$ host gentofte
gentofte.mosek.intranet has address 172.16.0.198
gentofte:~ admin$ host 172.16.0.198
198.0.16.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer gentofte.mosek.intranet.
gentofte:~ admin$ dscacheutil -q host -a name gentofte
name: gentofte.mosek.intranet
ip_address: 172.16.0.198

gentofte:~ admin$ dscacheutil -q host -a ip_address 172.16.0.198
name: gentofte.mosek.intranet
alias: 198.0.16.172.in-addr.arpa 
ip_address: 172.16.0.198
```

That looked fine. 
SO i tried seeing if the mac server could find any of my Open Directory users. It couldn't. I try to ping the DNS server and the OD server, and both pinged fine.

Also when i try going into preferences->User Accounts->Login Options, the window just freeze up, if the ethernet cable is in the machine.

I find it pretty weird, and i'm out of idea's of how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was YP bind. it still thought that it sould get the OD accounts from the old ip, so that was why it couldn't find them.

I deleted the file accociated with the domain in /var/yp/binding/ and restarted the system. The machine is now acting normal to ssh and logging in from gui.